# Excel to pdf command line macro - object doesn't support this property or method error 438

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently building a macro to export a excel worksheet (xls or xlsx) to a pdf file. I want to call the macro like this:

```
cmd.exe /C "C:/[...]excel.exe" /e /q C:/[...]/MacroFile.xlsm /a C:/[...]/filetobeconverted.xls
```

This is what I have so far

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Excel2Pdf()

Dim sPDFFilename As String
Dim Newfilename As String
    'Application.Workbooks.Open sFilename
    Newfilename = (Replace(ActiveSheet.FullName, ".xls", ".pdf"))
    Newfilename = (Replace(Newfilename, ".xlsx", ".pdf"))

  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Newfilename, xlTypePDF
  ActiveSheet.Close
  Application.Quit

End Sub
```

However, I'm getting:

> runtime error "438: object doesn't support this property or method"

Every nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in the code, which cause the `438` error:

- `ActiveSheet`  does not support the `Close` method.  Thus, this line here -   `ActiveSheet.Close` causes the error. Delete it and it would work quite ok.
- `ActiveSheet` does not have `FullName` property. It has `.Name`

To use the built-in intellisense in the VBEditor, declare the sheet as variable and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Then something like this appears:

[image]

Comment: Nor does it support `FullName`

Comment: If you want to close it, you can write: ActiveSheet.Parent.Close

Comment: This solved the issue. However, it prints to OneNote instead of PDF. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @maRei - Congrats! Now, you may consider marking the answer as accepted. For the question - I guess that the settings of the pc are made that OneNote opens the files with `.pdf` extension by default? Try to open the "printed" file with acrobat and see whether it is a pdf one.